# Normal distribution weakly converges to a normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $F_n(x)$ is a sequence of normal distribution functions and $F(x)$ is a distribution function. $F_n(x)$ weakly converges to $F(x)$ (i.e. $F_n(x)\rightarrow F(x)$ whenever $x$ is a continuous point of $F(x)$) How can I prove that $F(x)$ is also normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest proof of this uses characteristic functions. Suppose $e^{im_nt} e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2}/2} \to \phi (t)$ for all $t$ where $\phi$ is a characteristic function. Taking modulus on both sides we see that  $\sigma_n^{2}$ converges. Let the limit be $\sigma^{2}$. Now convergence of $e^{im_nt}$ for $|t|$ sufficiently small (which follows from the fact that $\phi (t) \neq 0$ for such $t$) shows that $m =\lim m_n$ exists. Now the limiting characteristic function is $e^{imt} e^{-t^{2}\sigma^{2}/2}$ which is  a normal characteristic function.